# Split BigInteger to specific number of digits

Tags: java, biginteger

I want to split BigInteger number 
`(1612513671536531537631747547475745713467754864474894674969787486558856856587856595095785859828347864647647545474665743827865765785635689266855775685657587586565858655985865858568585856858)`

into 20 digit numbers.How can I do this?Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want to split it from the start or from the end, or do you only want to split numbers with an exact multiple of 20 digits?

Comment: easiest to do a toString() and split that into pieces, I think.

Comment: split it from the start.End result should be as follows.

Comment: 16125136715365315376                                                   31747547475745713467

Comment: So 123456789012345678901 should become 12345678901234567890 and 1, or 1 and 23456789012345678901 ?

Comment: How is that split "into 20 digit numbers"?

Comment: yeap                                                                   So 12345678901234567891 should become 1234567890123456789 and 1

Comment: *"How can I do this?"*  Why would you want to?  What application feature this is supposed to implement?

Comment: This is a maths question.But I'm new to java.So I need a code to solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 12345678901234567891 should become 1234567890123456789 and 1

```
String s = bi.toString();
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 20)
    parts.add(s.substring(i, Math.min(i + 20, s.length())));
System.out.println(parts);
```

prints

[16125136715365315376, 31747547475745713467, 75486447489467496978, 74865588568565878565, 95095785859828347864, 64764754547466574382, 78657657856356892668, 55775685657587586565, 85865598586585856858, 5856858]

Comment: There is no operator to do this without using a loop ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to split it as bellow after taking it as a String

```
String s = "1612513671536531537631747547475745713467754864474894674969787486558856856587856595095785859828347864647647545474665743827865765785635689266855775685657587586565858655985865858568585856858";
    String [] numbers =s.split("(?<=\\G.{20})");


for(String num:numbers){
        System.out.println(num);
    }
```

and out put

```
16125136715365315376
31747547475745713467
75486447489467496978
74865588568565878565
95095785859828347864
64764754547466574382
78657657856356892668
55775685657587586565
85865598586585856858
5856858
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to a String and then use

```
String strBigInt = <yourBigInt>.toString();
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
while(strBigInt.length > 20){
    parts.add(strBigInt.substring(0,20));
    strBigInt = strBigInt.substring(20);
}
parts.add(strBigInt);
```

Comment: When I insert a number and run the code,the following error message is being displayed.

Comment: Syntax error on token ">", Expression expected after this token

Comment: @KillerCode You are supposed to replace that with your bigint variable. Also better use toString like in other answers, that cast will not work I think.